# Remove duplicate lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Sample.txt. Columns are tab separated.

```
id\kju9iu   134_Check_random    Roll_call
id\wer456   1989_Restraint  check_roll
id\kju9iu   134_Check_random    Roll_call
id\kju9iu   134_Check_random    Roll_call
id\wer456   1989_Restraint  check_roll
id\pol09i   ifwcheck    business
id\po92kc   CVSC    EGL
id\pol09i   ifwcheck    business
....
..
so on
```

**Expected Output**

```
id\kju9iu   134_Check_random    Roll_call
id\wer456   1989_Restraint  check_roll
id\pol09i   ifwcheck    business
id\po92kc   CVSC    EGL
....
....
so on
```

I tried using the regex : `^(.+?)\R(\1\R?)+` as well as `^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)` in the regular expression mode. Nothing worked.

I can't install TextFX plugin due to security issue in my organization.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : ^(.+)\r?\n(?=[\s\S]*?^\1$) did the trick. Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment to my answer, you may replace `\r?\n` with `\R`.